# Error - Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared, statistical-test

I'm trying to do chi-square test on the contingency table

```
                Satisfied More Or Less Not At All Sat
  Lower Class         299          787           1876
  Working Class      4594        10935           7660
  Middle Class       8913        10260           3679
  Upper Class         989          420            227
  No Class              0            0              0
```

I used the code `chisq.test(ct)` and got the following error

```
Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  ct
X-squared = NaN, df = 8, p-value = NA
```

When i looked up the error i found answers asking to stimulate the p-value `chisq.test(ct,simulate.p.value=TRUE)`

I still get an error

```
cannot compute simulated p-value with zero marginals Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  ct
X-squared = NaN, df = 8, p-value = NA
```

I want to know where I'm going wrong and whether I can perform some other test on the data.

Comment: Why do you have a no class class which has no elements? This seems to be unnecessary, have you tried removing it?

Comment: It tells you that the issue are the zero marginals (i.e., the "No Class" values). To me it seems like these are intended to indicate missing class values. Since you have none of these, why don't you remove the "No Class" marginal?

Comment: `chisq.test(ct[-5L, ])` worked on my laptop.

Comment: ```chisq.test(ct[-5L, ])``` works for me as well. Can u explain what ct[-5L] does? thanks anyways!! @ekoam

Comment: @Roland already explained to you the reasons behind. You can't use zero marginals for the Chi-square test. That code simply means running a `chisq.test` after removing the last row.